# How to get annotation used on inner generic type?

Tags: java, generics, reflection, annotations

My question is somewhat a little more advanced reflection problem.

Suppose you have a class:

```
import java.util.List;

public class Sample
{

    private List<@First List<@Second String>> field;

}
```

As you see, type of field is `List<List<String>>`. Assume you have 2 different annotations: `@First` and `@Second`. These annotations are put on this field's generic type, respectively. Now, my goal is to access these both annotations at runtime.

Here is my code:

```
Field field = Sample.class.getDeclaredField("field");
AnnotatedType annotatedType = field.getAnnotatedType();
AnnotatedParameterizedType annotatedParameterizedType = (AnnotatedParameterizedType) annotatedType;
```

When I invoke `getAnnotatedType()` on field, it returns me an `AnnotatedParameterizedType`.

```
AnnotatedType annotatedActualTypeArgument = annotatedParameterizedType.getAnnotatedActualTypeArguments()[0];
Annotation firstAnnotation = annotatedActualTypeArgument.getAnnotations()[0];
```

`getAnnotatedActualTypeArguments()` method actually gives me the `@First` annnotation.

```
ParameterizedType innerType = (ParameterizedType) annotatedActualTypeArgument.getType();
```

However, when I try to get type of the inner generic argument, it gives me a `ParameterizedType`. Which correctly defines the type of inner-most argument: `List<String>`. But, because it is not of type `AnnotatedParameterizedType`, I cannot access `@Second` annotation.

Is there any way I can access the second annotation as well at runtime?

Answer (score 2):

First of all the annotation type `Second` has to be declared with `@Retention` set to `RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME`, so that they are retained in the class files and can be read using reflection by the JVM.

You should be able to access the second annotation the same way you did with the first one. Convert `annotatedActualTypeArgument` to `AnnotatedParameterizedType`, then get the annotated actual type argument:

```
AnnotatedParameterizedType innerAnnotatedParameterizedType = (AnnotatedParameterizedType) annotatedActualTypeArgument;
AnnotatedType innerAnnotatedActualTypeArgument = innerAnnotatedParameterizedType.getAnnotatedActualTypeArguments()[0];
Annotation secondAnnotation = innerAnnotatedActualTypeArgument.getAnnotations()[0];
```